# Javascript client-side ORM

Tags: javascript, django, orm, client-side

On a project Im working on, I need to make several and somewhat complex queries. Im using javascript on the client-side, yet no frameworks. The backend is django and database is PostrgeSQL.

I was willing to make a small django adapter in this case for javascript, in order to use ORM of Django. But I dont think this is the best option.

I would not want to use only 10% of a framework just because of its ORM. Is there a light javascript option for this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you open to alternatives to django? If so there is express for nodejs, flask, etc..

Answer (score 1):

A light option? Not really. You wouldn't just straight up expose the Django ORM to the frontend. Django has probably the most well thought out REST implementation through http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ it's not terribly complex to use and integrates with the ORM.